# T-SQL Query which only displays rows where the value in one column matches the value in another column on another row

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Having exhausted my limited knowledge of tsql I hope someone may be able to help?

I have a table which holds relationship data such as ID, name, relationship and reciprocal relationship type, start and finish date etc.

Each row contains the Reciprocal ID for the other side of the relationship. See below.

From that I would like to present rows where the ID is equal to 1234 and 1236.

Thank you in advance for help with this.

Paul

```
+------+-------+------------+------------+----------+------------+---------+
| ID   | Name  | Start      | Finish     | Type     | Recip Type | RecipID |
+------+-------+------------+------------+----------+------------+---------+
| 1234 | Joe   | 01/05/2018 |            | Father   | Daughter   | 1235    |
+------+-------+------------+------------+----------+------------+---------+
| 1235 | Emily | 01/05/2018 |            | Daughter | Father     | 1234    |
+------+-------+------------+------------+----------+------------+---------+
| 1236 | Susan | 01/09/2017 | 01/05/2018 | Visitor  | Patient    | 1237    |
+------+-------+------------+------------+----------+------------+---------+
| 1237 | Harry | 01/09/2017 | 01/05/2018 | Patient  | Visitor    | 1236    |
+------+-------+------------+------------+----------+------------+---------+
```

Comment: What results do you want?

Comment: What criteria are you using to determine that you want the rows where ID is equal to 1234 or 1236? If it's arbitrary, then `select * from table where id in (1234, 1236)` will do the trick, but since all IDs are in both the ID and RecipID column self joins or existence checks alone won't do it for you.  We need more details in order to help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for `or`:

```
select t.*
from t
where id in (1234, 1236) or recipid in (1234, 1236);
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, just wondering how would this work across the whole table where I wouldn't know be able to insert all f the individual ID's?  Paul

Comment: @PaulE . . . This question is explicitly about exactly two ids.  If you have another question, then ask it as another *question*.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would do what you intend:

```
select t1.* 
from table t1 
where exists (select 1 from table t2 where t1.id = t2.recipid);
```

However, same could be also achieve via `self join`

Comment: Hi Yogesh, unfortunately that brings back all of the rows not just one of the paired rows.  Paul